# Run Time Error 91 - Excel vba from Access

Tags: excel, ms-access, runtime-error

I have a macro assigned to a button in an MS Access database that opens and updates a MS Excel spreadsheet that is linked to the database. I have it successfully working on every other run, meaning on the first button click it runs 100% successfully. I then close the workbook without saving and attempt to run it again and I receive an error 91 code. I've been researching and have added ranges etc. but I still get this run time error at the exact same line. ActiveCell.Value = myDate There's additional code after the error (hence the extra definitions) but right now I'm mainly concerned with this one. I want a user to basically be able to click the button and run their own reports without me being in the office to assist LOL

```
    Private Sub BtnExport_Click()
    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

    Dim wsCharts As Worksheet, wsResults As Worksheet, wsTable As Worksheet

    Dim OriginalSheet As String, myDate As String, FolderPath As String, _
    DollarAccuracy As String, IRA As String, Dollars As String,  _ 
    Counts As String, Cell1 As String, Cell1Minus As String

    Dim TotalDollarVar As Long, TotalDollar As Long, TotalSame As Long, 
    TotalAll As Long, _
    lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long, lastRow3 As Long, lastRow4 As Long



'Definitions
FolderPath = "C:\MyPath\Reports"
myDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy") 'Set the date for last month


  'Open the spreadsheet
    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\MyPath\Spreadsheet title.xlsx")
    appExcel.Visible = True
        Set wsCharts = myWorkbook.Worksheets("Charts")
        Set wsResults = myWorkbook.Worksheets("Results")
        Set wsTable = myWorkbook.Worksheets("Table")

    wsResults.Range("A2").Value = "Results " & myDate 'Put last month's date with the results

    wsResults.ListObjects("Table_Name1").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:= _
    xlFilterDynamic ' Filters the results table to last month

    wsTable.ListObjects("Table_Name2").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:= _
    xlFilterDynamic 'Filters the data table to last month

    wsCharts.Activate ' Make the charts tab active
        wsCharts.Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide the columns for entry
        Dim r As Range
        Set r = wsCharts.ListObjects("DollarAccuracy").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find _
        ("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not r Is Nothing Then

        lastRow1 = r.Row
                    DollarAccuracy = CStr(lastRow1)

            Dim StrDollar As String
            StrDollar = "A" & DollarAccuracy

             Dim rDollar As Range
             Set rDollar = wsCharts.Range(StrDollar)
             If Not rDollar Is Nothing Then
             rDollar.Offset(1, 0).Select
             ActiveCell.Value = myDate
             Selection.NumberFormat = "mmmm" 'Add last month to the "A" column for Dollar Accuracy
         End If
         End If
```

**New Code Here:**

```
    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim wsCharts, wsResults, wsTable As Worksheet
    Dim myDate, FolderPath, strDAa As String
    Dim SummaryRow, LastDARow, NextDARow As Long
    Dim rDA, rDAa As Range
   'Definitions
   myDate = Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "mmmm yyyy") 'Set the date for last month
Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    With xlApp
    .Visible = True
    Set xlWB = .Workbooks.Open("C:\Path\Workbook.xlsx", , False)
    End With
    Set wsCharts = xlWB.Worksheets("Charts")
        Set wsResults = xlWB.Worksheets("Results")
        Set wsTable = xlWB.Worksheets("Table")
    wsResults.Range("A2").Value = "Results " & myDate 'Put last month's date with the results
    wsResults.ListObjects("CycleCountResults").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:= _
    xlFilterDynamic ' Filters the results table to last month

    wsTable.ListObjects("PartsData").Range.AutoFilter _
    Field:=1, Criteria1:=xlFilterLastMonth, Operator:= _
    xlFilterDynamic 'Filters the data table to last month

    wsCharts.Columns("B:C").EntireColumn.Hidden = False 'Unhide the columns on the table tab for entry


        Set rDA = wsCharts.ListObjects("DollarAccuracy").Range.Columns(1).Cells.Find _
        ("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not rDA Is Nothing Then

            LastDARow = rDA.Row 'Define the row number for the last entry
            NextDARow = LastDARow + "1" 'Define the next blank row
            strDAa = "A" & NextDARow 'Define the date cell
            Set rDAa = Range(strDAa)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't defined which instance of Excel that you are referring to with `ActiveCell`, so it is trying to select a cell in the original instance, not the instance in which the workbook has been opened the second time.

If you avoid using `Select`, and just say

```
rDollar.Offset(1, 0).Value = myDate
rDollar.Offset(1, 0).NumberFormat = "mmmm" 'Add last month to the "A" column for Dollar Accuracy
```

you will probably be fine.

---

You should also check to make sure you are closing your instances of Excel correctly (it's not shown how or if you are doing that in the posted code) and you should consider using early-binding rather than late-binding if you intend to define all your variables using early-binding methods anyway.

Comment: I rewrote a lot of my code today and named cells instead of using the offset function. It corrected the above error but is now giving me a RunTime error '1004' message Method 'range' of object '_global' failed. on this line:  Set rDAa = Range(strDAa)

Comment: I put set = nothing for the excel definitions at the end of my code, if that's what you meant by closing excel. I am only posting up to the points of error

Comment: @rachelm920 (a) You should probably `Quit` your Excel application object before you set it to `Nothing`.  (b) `Set rDAa = Range(strDAa)`  is equivalent to `Set rDAa = ActiveSheet.Range(strDAa)` (because you haven't qualified `Range` with the specific worksheet you are referring to) so my guess as to why that is failing is that your `ActiveSheet` is a `Chart` and not a `Worksheet`.  Always qualify `Range`, `Cells`, `Rows`, `Columns`, etc with the object that they are referring to - so (and this is just a guess) maybe you wanted `Set rDAa = wsResults.Range(strDAa)`.

Comment: wsCharts is the name of the tab (instead of sheet1 etc.) I have the results table on a separate tab due to formatting it for print, the cell sizes wouldn't work together. The end of the code exports it to a PDF for printing and sharing. I will try wsChart as part of it tomorrow morning and see if that eliminates the problem. Thanks for helping this self taught coder 

Comment: @rachelm920 Although I doubt if it is causing a problem in your code, be aware that `Dim rDA, rDAa As Range` is declaring `rDA` to be a `Variant` and `rDAa` to be a `Range`.  (From what I can read of your code, I expect `rDA` will become a `Variant/Range` subtype.)  You probably wanted to use `Dim rDA As Range, rDAa As Range`.  (Several other lines are coded in a similar way.)

Comment: Yes I was trying to give them names to where they go. The DA stands for "dollar accuracy" which is the name of the table

Comment: Actually, the reason why `Range(strDAa)` will fail (**and won't once you qualify it with the worksheet object**) is nothing to do with the `ActiveSheet` being a `Chart` - I just remembered that you are running this from Access with both an implied early-bound Excel application as well as a late-bound Excel application, and your workbook is open in the late-bound instance (i.e. in `appExcel`).  But an unqualified `Range` knows nothing about that instance, so that is why it will crash - there's no workbook open as far as `Range` knows.  Qualifying it should make it work.

Comment: That worked! I used wsCharts before the range and the errors went away.